# Accessing Postgresql from terminal

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, postgresql

After recently setting up Postgresql on my Raspberry Pi I created an account which is not a power user. Initially to set this up I entered

```
psql
```

from the terminal and then executed

`createuser pi -P --interactive`

I responded N for superuser 
Y for create databases
Y for create new roles and then.

```
Create database test;
```

When I try to go to psql now using simply

```
psql
```

I get

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ psql psql: FATAL:  database "pi" does not exist
```

I can go to psql test and create databases there, but I was wondering what causes this behavior.

Does terminal automatically pass the Pi user credentials to postgresql or is it logging me in with my system's Pi Account?

Comment: Creating a user account does *NOT* create a database for them to use in the same process.  `createdb -O pi pi` and then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing the `psql` command you are attempting to use to connect to your Postgresql server.  Though, I can possibly explain what is going on without that information.

If you do not specify a user in your `psql` command, it tries to use the username you are currently logged in as.  If you do not specify a database, it will attempt to load a database of the same name as the user.

The error you are getting is `database "pi" does not exist` which indicates it could not load the database `pi`.  In your posted question, you mention creating the username `pi` and the database `test`.  You would want to specify to load the `test` database in your `psql` command:

`psql --dbname=test`

If you were not logged in as the `pi` user, you would want to pass the username in your `psql` command:

`psql --username=pi --dbname=test`

If none of that works, post your `psql` command in your question and we can get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Thank you. I believe this is the case. I have edited the post to more accurately show what commands I am executing. When I have a chance to experiment with these options, I'll add a follow up comment. Thanks for helping a noob out.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by:
sudo su postgres

psql

CREATE DATABASE pi;

\q

exit

then from the pi account when you just use psql it will let you into the pi database

otherwise when you do psql you have to specify a database to connect to (if you just do psql it thinks you want to connect to database pi(your unix username)

and if you wanted to connect to that test database from the pi account:

psql --dbname=test

this way psql doesnt try to connect you to the pi database.

hope this helps someone.